# Binding Image to CarouselView

Tags: sqlite, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a database that I have created using SQLite. I'm using Xamarin.Forms. I would like to display a carousel of images using CarouselView.FormsPlugin and although I have looked at documentation I have had no luck in displaying it on my app.

I have the CarouselViewRenderer.Init() in the Android MainActivity.cs file. However, no images are displayed.

XAML:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions;assembly=CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions"
             x:Class="HostelRentalApp.HostelDetailsPage">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <forms:CarouselViewControl x:Name="CRSLImages" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <forms:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding .}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </forms:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
            </forms:CarouselViewControl>
    </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

CS:

```
public HostelDetailsPage (HostelInfo hostel)
        {
            var images = App.Database.GetHostelImageList(0);
            this.CRSLImages.ItemsSource = images;
        }
```

SQLite Query:

```
public List<HostelImages> GetHostelImageList(int id)
        {
            return database.Query<HostelImages>("SELECT Image FROM HostelImages WHERE Hostel_id = ?", id);
        }
```

[image]

The Query is returning the correct rows. As shown, when using a tracepoint, the image filenames are retrieved. However, the images are not shown on the UI. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Where are the actual images located?  Have you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows

Comment: The images are stored in the Resources/drawable directory with build action AndroidResource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ItemsSource` is a `List<HostelImages>` so your binding path should be

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
```